# why did bangaldesh purchase a large number of weapons and tanks

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Bangladesh is increasing its defense budget and processing a plethora of modern equipment and weapons from all over the world. What is the threat perception of Bangladesh, and why is it modernizing its armed forces?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Tor. Your question could potentially fit with the politics.stackexchange.com but would probably be better for r/Bangladesh subreddit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the politics of the country of Bangladesh with no connection at all to anything about Tor